# How do I structure out this for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have this line of code that I'd like to use for another function:

```
array=[[0 for column in range(width)] for row in range(height)]
```

How do I separate the for statement? I tried this:

```
    column = 0
    for row in range(height):
        row = 0
        array = [column[row]]
        return array
```

The output should be a list of lists with 0 as their elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```py
array = []
for row in range(height):
  array.append([0 for column in range (width)])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
array = [[0] * width] * height
```

This will create list of lists initialized with 0s

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

**Edit**

This will create N copies of the same list, so any change will affect all the lists. If you do want to update values use

```
array = [[0] * width for _ in range(height)]
```

Same results, but now there are N different lists.

Comment: This will almost certainly not behaved as expected. See what happens when you do `array[0][0] = 1; print(array)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, I edited my answer with an explanation and an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to define the array variables explicitly, i.e.

```
rows = []
for row in range(height):
    column = [0] * width
    rows.append(column)
```